# AWS host static website and access via DirectConnect

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-direct-connect

I want to host a static website and will access it via DirectConnect with a custom domain + HTTPS. I think CloudFront + S3 is not suitable in this case as traffic will go through internet (correct me if I'm wrong). What/where should I host my website? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you need Direct Connect for your use case. Direct Connect is to connect on-premises data center with aws with private connection. It takes a lot of work to set this up like a telecom provider setting up a router at aws locations where they connect this router with aws's etc. This is a big project and costs money. I highly doubt you need this to host a static website.

You can host your static website in S3 and probably buy a domain name in route 53, and map your S3 bucket to this domain name so you can access this site on the internet (public site). There are many tutorials to set this up.

Comment: in my case, I already have Direct Connect and website access will be going through that connection.